# How to have custom setter with check of the parameter for validity?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and I can't wrap my head around a extremely basic problem:

I want to have a custom setter and to check if the parameter value is valid (and throw exception if not).

My code:

```
class Test {
    var presni: Int = 1
        set(value) {
            if (value < 0) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Negative value");
            }

            presni = value
        }
}
```

but it gives me warning at the `presni = value` line: *Recursive property accessor*

What is the idiom in Kotlin for checking the parameter in a setter for validity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use the automatic [backing field](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) provided by Kotlin.
You can access to it using the `field` identifier.

```
class Test {
    var presni: Int = 1
        set(value) {
            if (value < 0) {
                throw IllegalArgumentException("Negative value");
            }

            // Assign the value to the backing field.
            field = value
        }
}
```

Comment: Conditioned throw can also be reduced to `require(value < 0) { "Negative value" }`

Answer (score 7):

To validate a value before saving it in the backing field you can also use the Vetoable Delegate.

This is an example:

```
var presni: Int by Delegates.vetoable(1,{ _, _, newValue ->
        newValue >= 0
    })
```

The official documentation says:

> If the callback returns `true` the value of the property is being set
>   to the new value, and if the callback returns `false` the new value is
>   discarded and the property remains its old value.