# Kotlin - how to validate data class

Tags: validation, kotlin

I have a class:

```
class Foo{
  var x:Long = 10
    set(value) {if( value < 0 ) throw IllegalArgumentException("error"); field=value}
}
```

Is it possible to validate these values in a more elegant way? For example - I want something like this:

```
class Foo( @Positive var x: Long) {
}
```

Is it possible? I want it to be lightweight - no reflections, just check on settler. Any suggestions?

Comment: Checkout this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895821/how-to-have-custom-setter-with-check-of-the-parameter-for-validity/46897164#46897164

Comment: You can also implement your own "Positive" delegate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little late on that. You can use the [Result](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/io/konad/Result.kt) class of [Konad](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad) library. You return Result.Ok when validation has success, or Result.Errors if it fails.
It also brings a simple API when you need to compose multiple validation results. See [usage example](https://github.com/lucapiccinelli/konad#usage-example) section. For your case you can do:

```
data class private constructor Positive(val value: Long){
     companion object {
         fun of(x: Long) = 
            if(x < 0) "$x is not positive. Should be positive".error()
            else Positive(x).ok()
     }
}

fun addPositives(x: Positive, y: Positive, z: Positive): Long = 
    x.value + y.value + z.value

val added: Result<Long> = ::addPositives.curry()
    .on(Positive.of(1))
    .on(Positive.of(-1)) // This is invalid -> returns Result.Errors
    .on(Positive.of(2))
    .result

when(added){
    is Result.Ok -> added.toString()
    is Result.Errors -> added.description  
}.run { println(this) } // This is going to print "-1 is not positive. Should be positive"
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the class this way:

```
class Foo( @field:Positive var x: Long)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Bean Validation (JSR-380) annotations to declare validation constraints on the values. The `@Positive` annotation will require the value to be larger than 0, so in your case you want to use `@Min(0)` instead:

```
data class Foo(@field:Min(0) var x: Long)
```

Note that it is still possible to create invalid instances, so you need to actually validate the value afterwards (manually, or using AOP and `@Valid`, depending on which framework you use):

```
val foo = Foo(-10)
val validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().validator
val validationExceptions = validator.validate(foo)
```

When everything is correct, the `validationExceptions` will be empty, otherwise you'll get a list of all violations, as demonstrated with this JUnit test:

```
class ValidationTest {

    @Test
    fun `should validate data class`() {
        val foo = Foo(-10)

        val validationExceptions = validator.validate(foo)
        Assertions.assertThat(validationExceptions).isNotEmpty();
        Assertions.assertThat(validationExceptions
            .map { "${it.propertyPath}: ${it.message}" })
            .containsExactly("x: must be greater than or equal to 0");
    }
}
```

When validating the value, you probably want to throw a cumulative `ValidationException`:

```
if (validationExceptions.isNotEmpty())
    throw ValidationException(validationExceptions.joinToString("\n")
    { "${it.propertyPath}: ${it.message}" })
```

Which here would result in:

> javax.validation.ValidationException: x: must be greater than or equal to 0